# Максимальная версия SDK

Tags: android, android-sdk

Подскажите пожалуйста, если в Gradle прописать maxSdkVersion 19, и загрузить приложение в маркет, будет ли оно отображаться для пользователей, у которых версия андроид выше 5ой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по [документации](https://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html) – нет, не будет. Google Play использует этот атрибут при выводе списка приложений:

> For devices already compiled with maxSdkVersion, Google Play will respect it and use it for filtering.

Стоит учесть, что этот атрибут является `deprecated` и Google [не рекомендует](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#max) его использовать.

Comment: Спасибо большое